# mysql table 2 unique column

Tags: mysql

I have a table, called tablen.

It has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablen` (
   `a` int(11) unsigned not null,
   `b` int(11) unsigned not null,
   unique key(a,b)
}
```

This table has 1 use.  I hit it with a row of data.  If it is found to be a new unique row not already in the table, it gets added, else I get the returned error code.

The main thing I guess is speed.  I don't have the facility to stress test the setup at the moment and so...

What would you say is the best format for this table?

Innodb or myisam?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of inserts and updates, go for InnoDB, because it has row locking. MyISAM has table locking, which means, the whole table gets locked when a record is inserted (queuing all other inserts). If you have far more selects than inserts/updates then use MyISAM which is usually faster there (if you also don't care for foreign keys).

Comment: Would innodb be better for the above use then?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest InnoDB in this case.